# error when publishing topology for lync server

Tags: authentication, topology, lync-server-2010

I'm getting an error when I try to publish topology for Lync server.

```
    Error: An error occurred: "Microsoft.Rtc.Common.Data.SqlConnectionException" "Cannot open database "xds" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'IVR\Administrator'."
```

What should I do ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Is 'IVR\Administrator' in the Domain Admins and RTCUniversalServerAdmins groups?

Here are some articles that may help:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg412915.aspx
- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ocsinterop/thread/2aac2342-f785-433b-b900-4c72b754c64c/
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg195733.aspx